# Using CSS Selector to click a button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I want to click this button using css_selector.

```
<div class="ui-buttonset">
    <button class="ui-button ui-dfault ui-text-only" type=" button"
role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class-"ui-button-text">Save</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

There are 2 buttons **save** and  **cancel**. They both have the same code.
How do I click the save button using css_selector?

I have tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button").click()`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What about `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button:first-child").click()`? Or `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button:last-child").click()`?

Comment: Are the buttons next to each other? Would it not be easier to add an `id` attribute? Or perhaps a wrapper around each button with a more specific `id` or `class`?

Comment: @MartinVseticka Thank you your suggestion works

Comment: @royalblue Super, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following selectors:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button:first-child").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.ui-button:last-child").click()
```